# How do I find the limits of a joint density function and calculate the inequalities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, transformation, density-function

The r.v.'s ${X_1}$ and ${X_2}$ are independent and equidistributed with density function
$$
f_X(x)=4x^3, 0 \le x \le 1, 
$$
and equal to zero otherwise. Set ${Y_1=X_1\sqrt(X_2)}$ and ${Y_2=X_2\sqrt(X_1)}$. Determine the joint density function of ${Y_1}$ and ${Y_2}$.

I have managed to calculate the joint density function using the transformation THM (change of variable) and got that it is equal to
$$
f_Y{_1},_Y{_2}(y_1,y_2)=[indpt.]=f_X{_1}((y_1^4/y_2^2)^{1/3})*f_X{_2}((y_2^4/y_1^2)^{1/3})*|{\mathbf J}|
$$
where the Jacobian is 
$$
|{\mathbf J}|=4/3*y_1^{-1/3}*y_2^{-1/3}
$$
which gives me the joint density
$$
f_Y{_1},_Y{_2}(y_1,y_2)=64/3*(y_1*y_2)^{5/3}.
$$
This is correct. However I am confused regarding how to find the "limits" where ${f_Y{_1},_Y{_2}(y_1,y_2)}$ is not zero. The answer is supposed to be
$$
0 < y_1^2<y_2<\sqrt(y_1)<1
$$
But I do not know how to calculate it.
How do I find this? Any help much appreciated.

Edit: Thanks for the comments. Could someone please just clarify by showing how to get that:

$$
\sqrt(y_1)<1
$$

Comment: Note that $$x_1=y_1^{4/3}y_2^{-2/3}\qquad x_2=y_2^{4/3}y_1^{-2/3}$$ hence the domain of integration is $$0<y_1^{4/3}y_2^{-2/3}<1\qquad 0<y_2^{4/3}y_1^{-2/3}<1$$ Now simplify these inequalities to $$0<y_1^2<y_2\qquad 0<y_2^2<y_1$$ and conclude.

Comment: @Did That should be an answer, not a comment!  +1, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I figured it out.

Since Did's comments below the stated question illustrates how to get

$$
0<y_1^2<y_2
$$
and
$$
0<y_2^2<y_1.
$$
By rewriting the second equation we get
$$
0<y_2<\sqrt(y_1)
$$
which we can add to the first equation above. This gives us:
$$
0<y_1^2<y_2<\sqrt(y_1)
$$

Now, the relationship that ${ y_1^2<\sqrt(y_1)}$ implies that ${ y_1<1}$ which means that ${\sqrt(y_1)}$ can never really become equal to 1, hence ${\sqrt(y_1)<1}$. And thus we have the sought inequality,
$$
0 < y_1^2<y_2<\sqrt(y_1)<1.
$$
Hope this helps someone else.